# Attraction of Two Ships in a Choppy Sea

Tags: waves

Do two ships close alongside each other in a choppy sea tend to be attracted together?

I have read conflicting reports of this phenomenon. One of them, saying that they *do*, gave a thorough but highly ... *synoptic* I think might be the right word ... or *top down* maybe ... explanation in terms of the re-radiation of the wave energy by the pair, & the state of the waves between them, & how a sort of *pressure* is a property of a *plenum* of waves that would be expected to be greater *beyond* the ships than *between* them, rather than "volume δV of water acts with force δF on area δA of the hull", or suchkind of more *bottom up* argument. I can't reproduce the argument in detail I'm afraid, but it *was* thorough, with each ship bobbing up & down represented as a *monopole* and the two ships creating an *energy-field* mediated by the waves, and arguing that the energy-field would have such-&-such a *shape* & that kind of thing. But I *would have thought* that a definitive answer to this question would be easier to come by than it *seems* to be, what with the *maritime art* being such an ancient & noble & widely practised one. If anyone's curious about this I'll see what I can find about it, as I'm recalling from memory something I read in a fluid mechanics textbook years ago. But I have seen mentions of the *existence* of the phenomenon in a *fair few* places.

Got a bit more detail already: some say it's an analogue of the *Casimir* effect.

Comment: Think of a surfer, the wave pushes her forward due to gravity due to the slope of the wave, like a skier on a hill.  So if one ship is lower than the other they will collide. If both ships are facing into the wave there is no danger but in a rough sea waves come from all directions.

Comment: Google "squat maritime" to see an analogous effect between a ship and a shallow bottom...

Comment: @PhysicsDave - - I accidentally wrote my answer to you as an answsr _to this post_!

Comment: @DJohnM -- I certainly will have a look at that. Thankyou.

Comment: @DJohnM -- Ah yes! The _hydrodynamic_ (& ærodynamic) effect of reduction in pressure _Bernoulli-theorem_ -wise,  due to the increase in speed of fluid through a constriction. It also applies to vessels _moving_ in parallel. Both these are thoroughly _undisputed_ effects. But that's not _really_ the sort of phenomenon that is being queried in this post - rather it's the _tending to 'conspire'_ of the forces on ships being _buffeted about_ in such a way as that the forces on the pair (of ships) _inward_ tend to preponderate. But that account of a ship being gotten under a bridge ...

Comment: ... by _relying_ on the squat effect: just _so daring_! What a stunt! But was it _necessary_ to _repeat_ the stunt going the other way!?

Answer (score 0):

@PhysicsDave - - 
The scenario is that of the ships being generally *buffeted about*  by the waves, rather than being *systematically tipped* in some particular direction. I found *some* stuff about this. There is *some* grounds for considering it *plausible* that in a choppy sea the random buffeting might end up *conspiring* in such a way as to cause the ships to tend to drift together. In the wikepdedia article on *the **Casimir** effect*, there is a short clip of two parallel plates in a small tank of water drifting together when a transducer excites the water with sonic vibrations ... so *analogues* of the Casimir effect are *plausible*.

I know! I ought to have put it under *comments*. I thought I *was* doing!

Comment: https://zenodo.org/records/883891 This is probably the Casimir effect analogue you are referring to. Could you please add a bit more details on the paper in your answer?